# How to remove symbols from an AreaChart in JavaFX2

Tags: charts, javafx-2

Is there a way to remove the symbols from an AreaChart? LineChart and ScatterChart has that functionality, but nothing available in AreaChart.

Alternately, if I can "fill" paint in the area under, in a LineChart (like in AreaChart), I could go with that as well.

My goal is to build an AreaChart without symbols - whether its by using a lineChart (fill the area under it somehow) or AreaChart - doesnt matter...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By trial and error, I found that you can use this css code to turn off the symbols on an AreaChart

```
.chart-area-symbol { -fx-background-color: null, null; }
```

Normally the first color is the color of the symbol stroke, and the second color is the color of the fill.  Set them both to null, and the symbol is not painted.

Alternatively, set the shape to a no-op:

```
.chart-area-symbol { -fx-shape: ""; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much - In your trial and error process, how did you figureout the stylesheet names? I mean is there a list of default names somewhere?  Also, I'd appreciate it if you could read my other question on AreaCharts here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306710/how-to-chart-real-time-streaming-data-using-areachart-in-javafx-2-concurrency

Comment: The complete set of css available for JavaFX is in the file caspian.css  See: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm

Comment: I do not have an answer for your other question.  I hope someone else does, because I'd like to know the answer myself!